# Parse xml in batch file and upload returned value using curl

Tags: xml, parsing, batch-file, curl

I have searched, found, tried and FAILED !

Anyway, Im sure someone here will be able to assist.

I need to pull a value from an xml located on a webserver and then upload the returned value to another server. The curl bit I can understand but thats it.

The value needed is from the sensor named "S - Indoor Temp" and the value which is in the value tag. The below xml extract is only showing two sensors but the server has around 50. Not sure it this matters.

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sensors>
<sensor><id>{B189A2C9-D66C-44C9-BE7C-62AEBF9E6166}</id><name>S - Indoor Temp</name><category>30</category><nativevalue>+015.3C</nativevalue><value>15.3</value><valuetype>string</valuetype><output>False</output></sensor>
<sensor><id>{8C579CED-B256-4CC2-8A35-9F904C48527C}</id><name>S - Outdoor Temp</name><category>30</category><nativevalue>+008.5C</nativevalue><value>8.5</value><valuetype>string</valuetype><output>False</output></sensor>
</sensors>
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What values gets each server and what the output should be. There's no "S - Indoor Sensor" test in your xml.

Comment: Sorry my mistake "S- Indoor Temp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see code below. it looks first for sensor name "S - Indoor Temp". It it is found - then it looks for tag "". If found - the value is taken and echoed: "echo value=!value!"

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set nameFound=false
set value=

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    set value=
    echo "%%a" | find "</sensor>" > nul
    if "!errorlevel!"=="0" set "nameFound=false"

    echo "%%a" | find "<name>S - Indoor Temp</name>" > nul
    if "!errorlevel!"=="0" set "nameFound=true"

    echo "%%a" | find "<value>" > nul
    if "!errorlevel!"=="0" (
        if "!nameFound!"=="true" (
            set value=%%a
            set value=!value:^<value^>=!
            set value=!value:^</value^>=!
            set "nameFound=false"
            echo value=!value!
        )
    )
)
```

For your latest text format try following code (much simpler):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1-11 delims=>" %%a in ('type "file.txt" ^| find "<name>S - Indoor Temp</name>"') do (
    set "value=%%k"
    echo !value! ^| find "</value">nul
if "!errorlevel!"=="0" (
    set "value=!value:</value=!"
    echo !value!
)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This seems a different approach to the first answer. Anyway.. Very odd but the value return was the whole line except the <value></value> tags ?????                                           'value=<sensor><id>{B189A2C9-D66C-44C9-BE7C-62AEBF9E6166}</id><name>S - Indoor Temp</name><category>30</category><nativevalue>+015.3C</nativevalue>15.3<valuetype>string</valuetype><output>False</output></sensor>'

Comment: Looks like it is diplaying the whole file content when it finds <value> tag. Please make sure you have only one tag/tag pair per line and CRLF at the end of each line. On my machine it diplays : C:\Temp>script.bat
value=15.3
value=1.3

Comment: I manage to get it to work as you did, by copying my data above and creating a file and that worked but The data above was wrong!! My Bad. I have added the correct data above. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please see correct data above as it does not work with it. Thanks Dan

Comment: I added some code in the answer to match you actual XML format. Please try now.

Comment: It worked!!!! I cant thank u enough. One more thing.. Instead of down loading the file from internet can the batch read the file directly? Dan

Answer (score 0):

I used S - Indoor Temp as the string to find. Change it to match your specs.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "Tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('type sensors.xml^|Find /N "S - Indoor Temp"') do (
  set /a num=%%a+2
  for /f "Tokens=2 delims=<>" %%b in ('type sensors.xml^|more +!num!') do echo %%b & goto :eof
)
```

Comment: Hello, Many Thanks for your response. I have tried the above but the batch file does not echo the value. It just terminates. I have tried searching though multiple similar codes without success. - From what I can interoperate from the code you provided you do understand exactly what I am after.